# Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name is empty from WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

**EDIT**

The simple question is, how can I get `Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name` to have the current user logon in WPF?

**END EDIT**

I'm trying to call an existing method (not in any sort of service; just a method in a POCO) that retrieves the current user with:

`Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name`

This code was written by someone else, and (presumably) works with his ASP.NET MVC project.  I'm trying to call this same method from WPF, and Name is now blank.

Is there anything I can do about this?

Comment: FYI, I know its a bit late, but I've added more information to my answer that may interest you.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Set `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` to `new WindowsPrincipal(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent())`.  You'll then reliably have the current principal for the lifetime of that thread.  You'll have to repeat this on any other threads you spin up.

EDIT:  I should also mention the [SetThreadPrincipal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.setthreadprincipal.aspx) and [SetPrincipalPolicy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.setprincipalpolicy.aspx) methods on AppDomain.  This should be done on application startup, and new threads created will now see this principal by default.  If this method isn't called, every new thread will start out with GenericPrincipal again.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why wouldn't `System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;` be reliable?

Comment: Its more reliable in that he'd have to do that every time, rather than setting the the principal on the current thread once.  Also, other functions which depend on the thread having a WindowsPrincipal (connecting to a Sql Server using Integrated Authentication, for example) will work, where as the answer you suggested only gets the name.  I guess I was assuming he'd be doing things other than just getting the logged on user's name.

Comment: The AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetThreadPrincipal method works great for me in WPF. Thanks for the tip. Thread.CurrentPrincipal is a lot of work otherwise.

Answer (score 6):

Try

```
System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
```

or:

```
Environment.UserName
```

Answer (score 1):

This also worked for me:

```
Thread.CurrentPrincipal = new WindowsPrincipal(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent());
```