# Directory.CreateDirectory issue with UNC path

Tags: c#, file-io, windows-services, directory

I have a windows service running under a particular account. The service creates a folder at some configured path and later log messages to this folder.

The path configured is a UNC path but has been mapped. When i deploy the service on test server i get an error - **"could not find part of the path** '`Z:\<some folder>`'.

So to be clear

```
Server1 - server on which service is insalled and running under `<Domain1>\<User1>` account
Server2 - \\Server2\LogMessages

<Domain1>\<User1> account has full permissions on \\Server2\LogMessages. 
Also \\Server2\LogMessages path has been mapped to "Z:\" on Server1.
```

I tried to log the thread identity under which code was running and added code to log

```
Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name
```

The thread's identity name returned blank. I thought it should have been the account under which the windows service was running (in this case "Domain1\User1").

I am confused and need help to understand what is going on. Thanks.

Comment: You have to set the principal of the thread when you create it in some instances. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6699440/thread-currentprincipal-identity-name-is-empty-from-wpf for an example. Does that help?

Comment: When you look at the task manager, does it show that your service is running under said account (the account that mapped the drive)? There are SHARE permissions, and NTFS permissions. Make sure that you have both set.

Answer (score 0):

The service is running under a specific user (Services or System) and not under a particular user. This is a common mistake since it seems like the service is running under a specific user (the one that started it)
Z: is mapped in a specific user account and the service cannot see it.
I suggest using absolute paths or communicating via the file system or Tcp/IP.

Comment: The op mentioned that his service is "running under a particular account".  I think this is the account that he used to map the drive.  If this is the case, then his service should see it

Answer (score 0):

As @Mudx pointed out, this is not really an issue with UNC paths so much as it is an issue with mapped drives being tied to an account.  The mapping is saved within your user's registry hive. An alternative to relying on the mapped drive is to have your service read a configuration file to determine where it should log. It can be as simple as a file with a one liner or you can add a property to your service.exe.config file or create an xml file that can also later be used to config other properties for your service in the future.

Comment: The file path is given during the installation and it stored in the service config file with all other entries. I am still not clear why would Thread identity be blank and not set to the account under which the service is running !!

Comment: This [article](http://wardyit.com/blog/michaelodeajones/archive/2008/07/29/why-is-thread-currentprincipal-identity-name-empty.aspx) explains that the principle is not automatically set.  Dash also linked a previous thread mentioning a workaround.

Comment: May I ask why you have not chosen to access your log location via the UNC path (store the UNC path in your config instead of the mapped drive).   If during installation your end user is choosing a map drive, then you can translate that map drive to its UNC equivalent [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/6f79f2b3-d092-431f-bc28-d15d93cf5d09/)